# how to make a form if you do not how much inputs you have?

Tags: php, forms, loops

I will try to make my question as easy as I can explained.

let say there is a table named `foods` in our database
the user inserts as much he wants in this table

```
id-------name
1--------apple
2-------orange
3-------water
```

....etc
and in this table there is a column for order called order

```
id-------name-------order
1--------apple-------10
2-------orange-------20
3-------water--------30
```

so, the user insert number into column, so when print the table it will be ordered by order column.
so far so good
Now, I'm trying to make an edit page, so the user can change the order, but my problem is how to handle the form well.
my code is working like this

1. I check how many food in the table
2. print all food
3. make an input next to each food

but I got stuck with this problem, I don't know how to write a code to sql UPDATE the table if I don't know how many inputs there are, usually I know how many I.
**I think it's by using while loop**, I didn't figure out, could help please

my codes:

```
    <form action="" method="POST">
$order_id = array();
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

                echo '
                <tr>
                  <td>'.$row['seq'].'</td>
                  <td><input type="text" value="'.$row['seq'].'" name="vertical-spin'.$row['id'].'"></td>
                  <td class="txt-dark">'.date('d-m-Y', $row['time']).'</td>
                  <td class="txt-dark">'.$row['title'].'</td>
                  <td>'; if($row['active']) {echo '<span class="txt-success">show</span>'; } else { echo '<span class="txt-danger">hidden</span>'; } echo '</td>
                  <td><img src="../food/'.$row['id'].'.jpg" alt="iMac" width="120"></td>
                </tr>
                ';
              }
    </form>
```

look like this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wp3FQ.jpg)

my problem is how to handle the values into sql UPDAUTE since I don't know how many values there are
I tried to save all update order inside an array_push and works but then how to insert it into the table and how I know which value is for which food ?!!

***I solved the problem:***

in the form I made two hidden inputs

```
echo '<input type="hidden" value="'.implode(",",$data_id).'" name="idindatabase">';
echo '<input type="hidden" value="'.count($data_id).'" name="count">';
```

to know how many inputs there are and to know what's there id in database

in submit action:

```
if (isset($_GET['submit'])) {
    $new_array_for_id = preg_split ("/\,/", $_GET['idindatabase']);
    $count_new = $_GET['count'];
    $forcount = 0;
    while($forcount<$count_new) {
        $menu_id = $new_array_for_id[$forcount];
        $new_sq = $_GET['neworder_'.$forcount];
        update_seq($dBconnection, $user_id, $menu_id, $new_sq);
        $forcount++;
    }
}
```

this code will save each new inputs one by one

function is

```
function update_seq($dBconnection, $user_id, $menu_id, $new_sq) {
      $sql = "UPDATE menu SET seq = '$new_sq' WHERE user_id = '$user_id' AND id = '$menu_id';";
      $result = mysqli_query($dBconnection, $sql);
      }
```

Comment: Can you please post your code? Likely using input names of arrays would work. You then just iterate over 1 of the names and you'd know how many fields are with. Question is too vague without code though.

Comment: I attached a the code

Comment: you need to have the user id associated to the order. you don't know who ordered what

Comment: `name="vertical-spin['.$row['id'].']"` then iterate over `vertical-spin`s the keys will be your ids.

Comment: You cannot mix PHP and HTML like this.